# AWS Cognito .NET Core 3.1 integration

Tags: .net-core, amazon-cognito

I'm rather new to .NET in general and I'm trying to create a simple authentication for my API using AWS Cognito. I've followed guides online but none seem to work for me. This is how I've configured my Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMemoryCache();
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddCookie()
        .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
        {
            options.ResponseType = Configuration["Authentication:Cognito:ResponseType"];
            options.MetadataAddress = Configuration["Authentication:Cognito:MetadataAddress"];
            options.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Cognito:ClientId"];
        });
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

I have properly filled out my configuration. When I protect a page through `[Authorize]` I get redirected to AWS Cognito to login and then I'm redirected to `https://localhost:5001/signin-oidc?code=...` where I get a blank page and an error in the console stating:

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler[52]
      Message contains error: 'invalid_client', error_description: 'error_description is null', error_uri: 'error_uri is null', status code '400'.
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler[17]
      Exception occurred while processing message.
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectProtocolException: Message contains error: 'invalid_client', error_description: 'error_description is null', error_uri: 'error_uri is null'.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.RedeemAuthorizationCodeAsync(OpenIdConnectMessage tokenEndpointRequest)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.HandleRemoteAuthenticateAsync()
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
      Connection id "0HLTB2GSVEPB1", Request id "0HLTB2GSVEPB1:00000013": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
System.Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
 ---> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectProtocolException: Message contains error: 'invalid_client', error_description: 'error_description is null', error_uri: 'error_uri is null'.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.RedeemAuthorizationCodeAsync(OpenIdConnectMessage tokenEndpointRequest)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.HandleRemoteAuthenticateAsync()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.HandleRequestAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
```

I've tried to make sure that it's not wrong on the AWS side, and I've been able to see that a code and state is sent back to the application.

Comment: When you set up your user pool, did you create it with a client secret? I ran into the same issue when the pool required a client secret.

Comment: @tobyb I'm sorry but I don't remember, was so long ago now :(